# SQL: How to select multiple COUNT values that share NAME field?

Tags: sql, derby

I have an APACHE DERBY database table named STUDENTS with the following rows:

```
_____________________________
| NAME  |COUNTER|   MONTH   |
-----------------------------
| bill  |   10  |   January |
-----------------------------
| bill  |   12  |   February|
-----------------------------
| bill  |   11  |   March   |
-----------------------------
| sam   |   14  |   January |
-----------------------------
| sam   |   9   |   February|
-----------------------------
| sam   |   22  |   March   |
-----------------------------
| hal   |   21  |   January |
-----------------------------
| hal   |   18  |   February|
-----------------------------
| hal   |   19  |   March   |
-----------------------------
```

I am trying to find the syntax to get the following output...

```
_________________________________
| NAME  |  JAN  |  FEB  |   MAR |
---------------------------------
| bill  |  10   |  12   |  11   |
---------------------------------
| sam   |  14   |   9   |  22   |
---------------------------------
| hal   |  21   |  18   |  19   |
---------------------------------
```

I tried the following:

```
select distinct(name), 
    (SELECT COUNTER FROM STUDENTS WHERE NAME = 'bill' AND month = 'january') as jan,
    (SELECT COUNTER FROM STUDENTS WHERE NAME = 'bill' AND month = 'february') as feb,
    (SELECT COUNTER FROM STUDENTS WHERE NAME = 'bill' AND month = 'march') as mar
    FROM STUDENT where name = 'bill'
```

...and it kind of works as a proof of concept for one student. However, it's wordy, it only works for one student, and it does not scale for any data from 
future months that I will add to the db. Meaning, I would like to be able to get just the last 3 COUNTER values for each NAME regardless of how many months of data exits in the db.

I have looked at multiple s.o. questions related to nested queries, but none of them helped.

Suggestions?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This is a classic "pivot" problem.  Using that keyword for searching S.O. answers may help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation

```
SELECT name,
       Max(CASE WHEN month = 'January'  THEN counter end) AS jan,
       Max(CASE WHEN month = 'February' THEN counter end) AS feb,
       Max(CASE WHEN month = 'March'    THEN counter end) AS mar
  FROM student
 GROUP BY name
```